# Which version of LibreOffice should I use?

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice

Which `LibreOffice` version should be used in Ubuntu 16.04?

How can I install it?

Comment: Version 5.1.6 is already installed by default.

Comment: I would go for the latest stable, as the installed 5.1.6 is a bit oldish.  Follow @Raphael s answer to install it.

Answer (score 3):

Asking for the correct one is a little vague as the current version in the repository maybe correct for you while it might not be the correct version for others. Similarly, the current version in the `ppa` maybe correct for you while it might not be the correct version for others.

---

Nonetheless, to install `Libreoffice` from the repo do:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

---

**EDIT**: As per [bartovan's](https://askubuntu.com/users/311788/bartovan) comment, the following `ppa` provides the latest package from **fresh branch**.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

---

To install the latest stable version of `Libreoffice`, visit their [release notes](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/release-notes/) page and get the version number of the latest stable package. Now, follow the below steps to install the latest stable package of libreoffice:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-X-X
```

**Replace X-X with the version number of latest stable version. E.g.: at the time of editing this answer the latest stable release was 5.3.7, so, in place of X-X I would write 5-3**.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Or to install pre-releases of `Libreoffice`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Comment: With 'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa' one does not install the PPA for the latest _stable_ version, but for a testing version. "Most of the packages in this PPA have only experienced minor testing -- in fact it is the place to enable a wider audience to test packages before they are published into the distro proper. In general, this PPA is _not_ for the average user to install without a closer look (if it would be, its packages would be in the main repositories)." [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)